# SSH push to git from remote server

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh

I am having a hard time with the following situation: We have a remote virtual server where we store our website files, I access this server through `ssh` connection in `ubuntu` terminal. On my current desktop `ubuntu` I have 2 ssh keys as it should be - one public and one private. In Git I have added my public key from my local machine. If I try to connect like this:

```
ssh git@gitlab.DOMAIN.com
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Welcome to GitLab, X X!
Connection to gitlab.DOMAIN.com closed.
```

If I connect to our remote server and try to perform git push git is asking me to provide a password for account git@gitlab.DOMAIN.com ?

Can you give me some directions as to where I am going wrong and how to handle this?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly.  You are able to connect to the gitlab server from your local machine but `git push` fails from your remote server.  You need to also set the keys for your push on the remote server.  You can either copy the .ssh/ directory to the home directory on the remote server so that it uses your keys.

Your connection to the remote server does not have access to your keys so it is being treated like any anonymous push and gitlab is trying to verify who you are.

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation - actually if I try to connect from my local machine to Git I receive the first error, git recognize me but the next line is connection to gitlab.domain.com closed ... 

I placed id_rsa and id_rsa.pub on the remote server in .ssh folder, chmod the perm and ran ssh-add but without success. When I try to login in git - it keeps asking me for git@gitlab.domain.com password and I didnt set any password... I tried to check  with "ssh-add -l" and I saw that  no keys were loaded.I guess this is the problem - no idea why is not loading the keys when they are over there...

Comment: The response that you get from your local is what is supposed to happen, that isn't an error.  Just setting the keys in your home directory on the local machine should allow you to push, pull changes from gitlab.

Comment: It was not loading the keys but after several tries they were loaded successfully and I was able to login into Git - thanks for your time!